# Refactoring code to elegantly change looping position

Tags: python, for-loop

Say, I have a 3-step procedure to run. They have to be run in order:

```
step1(x)
step2(y)
step3(z)
```

I want to test a certain step with different parameters. So I am dreaming to have a function `test(step_num)` to help me elegantly indicate the location of the loop. For example, `test(1)` should give me

```
for x in range(0,10):
    step1(x)
    step2(y)
    step3(z)
```

`test(2)` should give

```
step1(x)
for y in range(0,10):
    step2(y)
    step3(z)
```

and `test(3)` should give

```
step1(x)
step2(y)
for z in range(0,10):
    step3(z)
```

Is it possible to achieve this? Any built-in feature from python I can use? In the real-life application, the number of steps could be >=10, and that's why I think it could help reduce redundant code.

Comment: Are the x,y,z fixed and where you define them? Where for example you get value for y and z in test(1)?

Comment: @np8 Ideally each one will have a different range, defined somewhere else (for example, I have a dictionary storing all the ranges). But I feel it is not that of a trouble compared to the question of how to place a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Put the function calls in a list, then you can iterate through the list.

```
def test(index, *funcs):
    for f in funcs[:index-1]:
        f()
    for _ in range(10):
        for f in funcs[index:]:
            f()

test(1, lambda: step1(x), lambda: step2(y), lambda: step3(z))
```

Comment: A brilliant idea! :D One may further work with the elements in the list to have a different range for each iteration of different step.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be fine just putting the functions `step1`, `step2`, `step3` into a tuple and looping them over when needed. In python functions are **First Class Citizens**, meaning amongst other things that you can pass them to functions as parameters and store them into lists/tuples.

#### Implementation

Here is a full example implementation

```py
# Define some example functions for testing
def step1(x):
    print("step 1:", x)

def step2(y):
    print("step 2:  ", y)

def step3(z):
    print("step 3:    ", z)


funcs = (step1, step2, step3)


def test(step_num):
    d = dict(x="X", y="Y", z="Z")
    params = ("x", "y", "z")
    idx = step_num - 1
    for func, param in zip(funcs[:idx], params[:idx]):
        func(d[param])
    paramname = params[idx]
    for val in range(10):
        d[paramname] = val
        for func, param in zip(funcs[idx:], params[idx:]):
            func(d[param])
```

#### Testing the implementation

You did not provide the desired output, but this should be *exactly* like the code in the question would do:

```
print("test(1)")
test(1)
print("-" * 10)
print("test(2)")
test(2)
print("-" * 10)
print("test(3)")
test(3)
```

the output is

```
test(1)
step 1: 0
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
step 1: 1
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
step 1: 2
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
step 1: 3
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
step 1: 4
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
step 1: 5
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
step 1: 6
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
step 1: 7
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
step 1: 8
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
step 1: 9
step 2:   Y
step 3:     Z
----------
test(2)
step 1: X
step 2:   0
step 3:     Z
step 2:   1
step 3:     Z
step 2:   2
step 3:     Z
step 2:   3
step 3:     Z
step 2:   4
step 3:     Z
step 2:   5
step 3:     Z
step 2:   6
step 3:     Z
step 2:   7
step 3:     Z
step 2:   8
step 3:     Z
step 2:   9
step 3:     Z
----------
test(3)
step 1: X
step 2:   Y
step 3:     0
step 3:     1
step 3:     2
step 3:     3
step 3:     4
step 3:     5
step 3:     6
step 3:     7
step 3:     8
step 3:     9
```

#### Notes about the implementation

- The `test`is looping over the functions that are stored in the `funcs` tuple. Could be also passed as argument, if needed.
- Default parameter values for `x`, `y`, `z` were not given in the question, but I just created a default parameter dictionary `d` for it.
- The same dictionary `d` is used inside the loops, when you want only one of the values (`x`, `y` or `z`)  change.